# Setting up a custom attribute form to a WFS-T in GeoServer

Tags: qgis, geoserver, wfs-t

Does GeoServer allow to apply a default style containing a custom attribute form to a WFS-T layer in GeoServer? Maybe it's not possible ?

I have loaded my QML file in the GeoServer style editor but no form is linked to my WFS-T layer when I load it in QGIS.

Comment: can you explain what you mean by "default style containing a custom attribute form"?

Comment: I want my WFS-T layer to be ready to be edited by mean of the custom attribute form when I load it to QGIS